# Android Volley Why does JsonObjectRequest does not call onResponse

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get my volley `JsonObjectRequest` working. When calling the `getById()` meth, `onResponse()` does not get called. I already have a working post request. So the connection parameters are correct. I do not get any error response or helpfull responses in LogCat.

I created a test class in order to isolate the `getById()` method.

```java
public class Test {

    Customer customer;
    public Customer getById(int id) {

        Log.i("CustomerDAO getById", "getById called");
        String urlJsonObj = "http://192.168.0.39:3000/Customers/" + id;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object

                    customer = new Customer(response.getInt("customernumber"), response.getString("name"),
                        response.getString("lastname"), response.getString("phonenumber"),
                        response.getInt("addressid"), response.getString("password"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Exception:", e.toString());
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("GetByIdErrorResponse", error.toString());
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

This is the singleton `RequestQueue` class.

```java
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i("RequestQueue= ", mRequestQueue.toString());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

This is how I call the `getById()` method

```java
Test test = new Test();
Entities.Customer check = test.getById(1);
```

Comment: Here is the response {"customernumber":1,"name":"string","lastname":"string","phonenumber":"string","addressid":1,"password":"string"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code. Since volley is an asynchronous networking library, you can't return the result from the network as you have done. You are initializing your `Customer` model class inside OnResponse and returning it from outside of it.
So what will be happening when you perform this operation is

**Creates Request -> Adds to Request Queue -> getById() method returns null**

The return statement, at last, won't wait till the response arrives. You'll be getting null every time. So what you have to do is to implement a custom callback when the API returns a result or error.

Create an interface for inside Test class for handling API response.

```
interface APICallback {
  void onSuccess(Customer customer);
  void onError(String error);
}
```

Pass these interface implementation to the getById() method along with id

```
public void getById(int id,APICallback callback) {
  ....
}
```

call methods on result

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object

                    Customer customer = new Customer(response.getInt("customernumber"), response.getString("name"),
                            response.getString("lastname"), response.getString("phonenumber"),
                            response.getInt("addressid"), response.getString("password"));
                    callback.onSuccess(customer);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Exception:", e.toString());
                }

            }
```

```
 @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("GetByIdErrorResponse", error.toString());
                callback.onError(error.toString());
            }
```

and now you can call getById() as follows

```
Test test = new Test();
        test.getById(1, new Test.APICallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Customer customer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {

            }
        });
```